# Не работет v-spacer в app-bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Хочу разделить app-bar на две части: чтобы слева был *v-app-bar-nav-icon*, а справа название секции. Для этого решил использовать **v-spacer**, но он не работает.

Код следующий:

```
<template>
    <v-app-bar
        app
        dense
        elevate-on-scroll
        floating
    >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon/>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-title>Название</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

Помогите решить данную задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я применил к *v-app-bar* неправильный аргумент **floating**, который делает его inline-flex. Чтобы всё работало, просто нужно его убрать.